# Libreoffice graphics problem

Tags: libreoffice, intel-graphics, ubuntu-mate

I'm using Ubuntu MaTE 16.04 and from the start I have had problems with Libreoffice. Although the program seems to work okay it has several graphics issues while opening and closing menus etc. Once I wanted to save a document and only the title of the box was there, no options were showed and the box was just plain gray.

What could be the cause for this and how could I solve it? I have tried reinstalling several times already. I'm using Intel HD graphics 520. MS Word with Wine works okay and there are no graphics issues there. Same goes with WPS office, but I really liked LibreOffice when I last used it a couple of years ago and then it worked just fine.

These black boxes appear every time I open and close menu:
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately I can not really help you, as I dont use that graphic driver, but I have solved similar issues with libreoffice in the past by changing my graphics driver. You could also try to toggle "Use OpenGL for all rendering" under Options --> Libreoffice --> View in Libreoffice.

Comment: Fixed the problem, also deleted libreoffice from .config folder at /home and now it's working fine. Thank you anyway! ;)